# Mongoengine how to reset SequenceField after new year?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

In my models I have one EmbeddedDocument Number which has a sequence field (it is not the primary key), this field is used as string concatenated part to generate a paper title (this way the field really needs to be sequential, as business rule).

The rule is: when the year begins, the sequence number has to restart the count and start counting from 1 again.

Ex:

```
...
12/30/2018 -> sequential_value = 545
12/30/2018 -> sequential_value = 546
12/31/2018 -> sequential_value = 547
01/01/2019 -> sequential_value = 1
01/01/2019 -> sequential_value = 2
...
```

My model:

`class Number(EmbeddedDocument):
    sequential_value = SequenceField(required=True)`

I'm searching about if there's a way to use the parameter *[value_decorator](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.SequenceField)* to restart the sequence field as it accept a callable, but I didn't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by changing my approach.
Looking at how mongoengine handles the [SequenceField](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/fields.py#L1874):

### fields.py

```
counter = collection.find_and_modify(query={'_id': sequence_id},
                                         update={'$inc': {'next': 1}},
                                         new=True,
                                         upsert=True)
```

Using the same approach I've created a function, that does the same, but uses 2 ids and the year as the query id:

```
next_number = collection.find_and_modify(
    query={'_id': oid+'_'+oeid+'_'+str(year)}, 
           update={'$inc': {'next': 1}},
           new=True,
           upsert=True)
```

So... this way every time that an object is created I use this function to generate the next sequence number and when the year changes a new row is created, so sequence number will start from 1 again.

Comment: Have the same issue, you inherited from SequenceField?

Comment: @mikazz, actually no, as is shown in the answer, I just created that new function and I use it every time before creating a new register.